# Django: gettext raises ValueError: 'plural forms expression could be dangerous'

Tags: python, django, gettext, django-haystack

If a auto generated django.po file contains the following line in its header

```
"Plural-Forms: nplurals=INTEGER; plural=EXPRESSION;\n"
```

"manage.py runserver" raises

```
gettext.py", line 93, in c2py
raise ValueError, 'plural forms expression could be dangerous'
ValueError: plural forms expression could be dangerous
```

If i remove the line everything works.
What does the header mean?
Why is it somtimes generated (for example localisation of the haystack app)?
What das the error message mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that your translator forgot to [fill it in properly](http://www.gnu.org/software/hello/manual/gettext/Plural-forms.html).

Comment: Actually this happend when I copied a translation file to another.

Comment: Does this mean if values are left empty?