# plural forms expression could be dangerous

Tags: django, internationalization

I've looked at this question: [Django: gettext raises ValueError: 'plural forms expression could be dangerous'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935704/django-gettext-raises-valueerror-plural-forms-expression-could-be-dangerous) and while it helps me understand the issue it doesn't solve it.

I have a pretty vanilla [django-cms](https://www.django-cms.org/) install, and one of the languages needs to be Polish, a language with more than one plural form.

I've been looking at how to fix this, but haven't gotten very far. `django-cms` uses an app for hierarchical trees called `mptt` and this is the first (and only?) application it trips on, while running the django.mo file for the *pl* locale.

See the traceback here: http://dpaste.com/684737/

---

Comment: Are you sure that your locale file has all correct translations? Answer to the linked question suggests this exception means that file hasn't been filled properly.

Comment: could this be the issue @WTK: https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt/commit/4b6a9758396450651bc2d02b2c7d49bac6cd3f25

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the following line wasn't removed in the 0.5.1 install of django-mptt:

```
"Plural-Forms: nplurals=INTEGER; plural=EXPRESSION;\n"
```

The changeset can be found here: https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt/commit/4b6a9758396450651bc2d02b2c7d49bac6cd3f25

This issue has been fixed as of 0.5.2 and upgrading to this version makes the error go away.

Comment: For future readers, removing this line ( ` "Plural-Forms: nplurals=INTEGER; plural=EXPRESSION;\n" ` ) from your *.po* file solves the issues if you get the error `ValueError: invalid token in plural form: EXPRESSION`