# Django - ValueError: plural forms expression could be dangerous

Tags: python, django, internationalization, gettext

I'm working with Django 1.9 in Microsoft Visual Studio. Also I'm using a virtual env, where all the needed python packages are installed. When I try to compile messages in order to add translation function to the site, the following error is raised:

```
ValueError: plural forms expression could be dangerous
```

Update 1. Stacktrace:

```
Internal Server Error: /
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\path-to-project\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 123, in get_response
response = middleware_method(request)
File "C:\path-to-project\env\lib\site-packages\django\middleware\locale.py", line 26, in process_request
translation.activate(language)
File "C:\path-to-project\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\__init__.py", line 154, in activate
return _trans.activate(language)
File "C:\path-to-project\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\trans_real.py", line 216, in activate
_active.value = translation(language)
File "C:\path-to-project\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\trans_real.py", line 205, in translation
_translations[language] = DjangoTranslation(language)
File "C:\path-to-project\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\trans_real.py", line 114, in __init__
self._add_installed_apps_translations()
File "C:\path-to-project\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\trans_real.py", line 160, in _add_installed_apps_translations
translation = self._new_gnu_trans(localedir)
File "C:\path-to-project\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\trans_real.py", line 140, in _new_gnu_trans
fallback=use_null_fallback)
File "C:\Python27\Lib\gettext.py", line 481, in translation
t = _translations.setdefault(key, class_(fp))
File "C:\Python27\Lib\gettext.py", line 182, in __init__
self._parse(fp)
File "C:\Python27\Lib\gettext.py", line 318, in _parse
self.plural = c2py(plural)
File "C:\Python27\Lib\gettext.py", line 95, in c2py
raise ValueError, 'plural forms expression could be dangerous'
ValueError: plural forms expression could be dangerous
```

I've read about that ([plural forms expression could be dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8793513/plural-forms-expression-could-be-dangerous) and [Django: gettext raises ValueError: 'plural forms expression could be dangerous'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935704/django-gettext-raises-valueerror-plural-forms-expression-could-be-dangerous)), but the only solution I found is to remove lines referred to plural translations, for example:

```
"Plural-Forms: nplurals=2; plural=(n != 1);\n"
```

If I remove those lines in my translations files, it still raises the same error, because it takes into account other files located at the virtual env.

Update 2: If I run the server from the command line, using

```
python manage.py runserver
```

there's no problem, everything is going right. However, when I run the project from Visual Studio, the error is raised.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide the stacktrace? Maybe you could notify the maintainers of the buggy library of this incompatibility.

Comment: Stacktrace provided. This error is raised four times.

Comment: first - try to identify which translation file is generating this error, removing this line is not a solution, there maybe a difference on env variables/locale settings when running from shell vs visual studio

Comment: Could you solve this problem?